# Documentation on how to use CFHTTP method=options

Tags: web, coldfusion, protocols, http-options-method

I can't really find an example of `cfhttp method=options`.

I am seeing documentation on many websites that `cfhttp` has a method named `options`, but they don't really show how we can make it work. I tried to search for http `options` but could not get much about how to use it, what is the practical use of this and how it can be implemented.

Comment: Try something and if it works great. If not, SO is a great place to post a question on how to get it to work for your needs.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that might involve the cfhttp tag?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "options"? For questions about how to use the `cfhttp` tag, in general, start with [the documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html). If you are asking about *http OPTION*, that is a different question altogether. Either way, can you please clarify your question?

Comment: `cfhttp` method has the `options`, what is the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

> This is from ColdFusion 9 docs, in my opinion the official docs for more  recent ColdFusion versions are not presented very well, so, I always go back to cf9 docs if I can. There is some code example there too.

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html

```
<cfhttp  
    url = "server URL" 
    charset = "character encoding" 
    clientCert = "filename" 
    clientCertPassword = "password" 
    columns = "query columns" 
    delimiter = "character" 
    file = "filename" 
    firstrowasheaders = "yes|no" 
    getAsBinary = "auto|yes|no|never" 
    method = "method name" 
    multipart = "yes|no" 
    name = "query name" 
    password = "password" 
    path = "path" 
    port = "port number" 
    proxyServer = "host name" 
    proxyPort = "port number" 
    proxyUser = "username" 
    proxyPassword = "password" 
    redirect = "yes|no" 
    resolveURL = "yes|no" 
    result = "result name" 
    textQualifier = "character" 
    throwOnError = "yes|no" 
    timeout = "time-out period in seconds" 
    username = "username" 
    userAgent = "user agent"> 

    cfhttpparam tags [optional for some methods] 

</cfhttp>
```

---

> Another good resource is https://cfdocs.org/cfhttp which has examples with the `script` syntax, something like:

```
cfhttp(method="GET", charset="utf-8", url="https://www.google.com/", result="result") {
    cfhttpparam(name="q", type="formfield", value="cfml");
}
writeDump(result);
```

---

> Also, the current official Adobe ColdFusion documentation can be found at https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/user-guide.html

- `cfhttp` tag at https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html
- `cfhttpparam` tag at https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttpparam.html